# Cannot resolve dependency to the homegrown module

Tags: java, grails, plugins, dependencies

I have a project, that consists of two modules - core and web.
Core module contains some domain classes and services, while web module has controllers and other front end staff.
If I put controller into the core module I can do ***grails run-app*** and then access my service directly via REST plugin in Chrome browser.
But when controllers are in web module I cannot resolve dependency between these modules.
In the **BuildConfig.groovy** for the web module I have

```
    plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.53"

    compile ":myapp-core:0.1-SNAPSHOT"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.0"
    compile ':cache:1.1.6'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
    compile ":angular-annotate-asset-pipeline:1.1.2"
    }
```

**BuildConfig** for the core looks like:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"

grails.project.fork = [
// configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked    compilation is required
//  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

// configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
// configure settings for the run-app JVM
run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the run-war JVM
war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the Console UI JVM
console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
//legacyResolve true
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // uncomment to disable ehcache
     excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
    // from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}
dependencies {
            compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.3.2'
}

plugins {

    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

    //plugin for consuming REST web services
    compile ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3"

    //plugin for consuming REST web services            
    build(":release:3.0.1") {
        export = false
    }
  }
```

}

When I am running build for the web module I am always getting following errors:

> |Loading Grails 2.4.3
>   |Configuring classpath
>   Error |
>   Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:myapp-core:zip:0.1-SNAPSHOT in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>   Error |
>   Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:myapp-core:zip:0.1-SNAPSHOT in grailsCentral (hyperlink to repo.grails.org removed) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>   Error |
>   Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:myapp-core:zip:0.1-SNAPSHOT in grailsCentral (hyperlink to repo.grails.org removed) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>   Error |
>   Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:myapp-core:zip:0.1-SNAPSHOT in grailsCentral (hyperlink to repo.grails.org removed)
>   |Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.

And myapp-core.zip file really does not exist in the .m2 repository.
Although it does create proper directory chain there but it contains only resolver-status.properties file.
I went through the Grails documentation and Manning book but still cannot find the resolution.
In plain old Java with maven it is a piece of cake, but in Grails, despite all the claims of how easy and straightforward it is, I beating my head against this wall for a week.

Help me, please-please-please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grails.plugin.location` as mentioned [in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html) or you can run [maven-install](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/ref/Command%20Line/maven-install.html) to install it locally.